# Rails : fighting long http response times with ajax. Is it a good idea? Please, help with implementation details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, divide-and-conquer

I've googled some tutorials, browsed some SO answers, and was unable to find a recipe for my problem.

I'm writing a web site which is supposed to display almost realtime stock chart.
Data is stored in constantly updating MySQL database, I wrote a find_by_sql query code which fetches all the data I need to get my chart drawn. Everything is ok, except performance - it takes from one second to one minute for different queries to fetch all the data from the database, this time includes necessary (My)SQL-server side calculations. This is simply unacceptable.

I got the following idea: if the data is queried from the MySQL server one point a time instead of entire dataset, it takes only about 1-100ms to get an individual point.

I imagine the data fetch process might be browser-driven. After the user presses the button in order to get a chart drawn, controller makes one request to the database and renders, say, a progress bar, say 1% ready. When the browser gets the response, it immediately makes an (ajax) request, and the server fetches the next piece of data and renders "2%".

And so on, until all the data is ready and the server displays the requested chart.
Could this be implemented in rails+js, is there a tutorial for solving a similar problem  on the Web? I suppose if the thing is feasible at all, somebody should have already done this before.

I have read several articles about ajax, I believe I do understand general principles, but never did nontrivial ajax programming myself.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could load the page with a div that displays an animated gif (indicating "working").  Then, use body onload to launch your ajax request and replace the contents of that div.

```
<body onload="some function call to Ajax.Updater('chart')">
<div id="chart">
  <img src="working.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: This is really a good way to do it. The user knows it that your application is working to crunch the data and you can use the same programming logic that you have already written.